# How to configure build for build undependent projects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I have a web project (asp.net) and I have several modules which should building in folder of the main project.

I can't find information about it.

I would like just build the main project and all modules should build too, but they not dependent with the main project.

Comment: Why not just add references on these modules (you mean class libraries?) to your main project? It doesn't matter that they actually are not dependent, but this would make them build every time main project is built and put their `.dll` to bin folder, so kind of solves your problem.

Comment: It's main idea. Modules should be optional and apply without dependency

Answer (score 0):

Well, there still would be some dependency involved. You can use [MsBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx) task to build your projects along with main project. There are several options on how to include msbuild script to your solution, here is one of possible ways that allows to change the list of modules without reloading the MainProject and without adding dependencies to it.

Let's say we have MainProject and 2 modules: ClassLibrary1 and ClassLibrary2. Create a BuildModules.csproj file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="BuildModules" ToolsVersion="4.0">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ModuleProject Include="ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj"></ModuleProject>
        <ModuleProject Include="ClassLibrary3\ClassLibrary3.csproj"></ModuleProject>
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <Target Name="BuildModules">
        <MSBuild Projects="@(ModuleProject)" Properties="OutputPath=..\MainProject\Bin\Debug;Configuration=Debug;" ContinueOnError="true">
        </MSBuild>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Now this is a concept only, so I've hardcoded the path to bin\debug folder. `ContinueOnError` is true so in case some error occurs, it doesn't affect on MainProject build process. Put this file in your solution root folder.

Now in MainProject properties on Build Events tab add the following Pre-build command:

```
call C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe $(SolutionDir)BuildModules.csproj
```

The path to msbuild.exe may vary.

Now each time you build, it would rebuild your assemblies and you can easily change the list of modules in your BuildModules.csproj file.

#### UPDATE 1:

TFS not deploying all files. I guess this is because of our hardcoded paths to msbuild and etc. Try moving Pre-build command to MainProject.csproj file, in BeforeBuild target:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <MSBuild Projects="..\BuildModules.csproj" Properties="Configuration=Debug"/>
</Target>
```

I'm not sure about the path though, but should be like this. And remove Pre-build command from build.

Comment: Set `ContinueOnError=false` and run again, what does it say? Are the paths to your projects correct?

Comment: Yes, it was incorrect path. but now I can't deploy from TFS and msbuilder. An agent copy all files, but in IIS folder didn't apear

Comment: @Mediator, hmm. Possibly Pre-build command not firing. I've updated my answer, so instead of Pre-build we use BeforeBuild target in project. It has to be executed in TFS, so I hope it helps.

Comment: it is not helped. files created in agentbuild but not not copy to iis folder

Comment: What do you use to copy? When does the copy begins, do the files exist? If files are created, I guess this makes your original issue solved?